# Why JavaScript/jQuery filtered list doesn't work in iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari

I've created a list, which is sortable by a dropdown select menu. I have this sitting within a Bootstrap framework... not really anything unique. When I add in a hidden attribute for all the Justice League, as well as the Justice League menu option, it works as expected on all desktop browsers and android Chrome/Firefox. It's **not** working on any iOS device, whether it's Safari or Chrome for iOS.

Is there something about the hidden attribute that doesn't work on iPhones?

I've tried it on iPhones 5, 7 and 10.

Keep in mind that it might work in here, or in the [codepen](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/NZoebZ) link I've included, so I don't really know where to go with this.

What possible reasons could be for this?

```js
var filterActive;

function filterCategory(category) {
  if (filterActive != category) {
    // reset results list
    $('.filter-cat-results .f-cat').removeClass('active');
    // elements to be filtered
    $('.filter-cat-results .f-cat')
      .filter('[data-cat="' + category + '"]')
      .addClass('active');
    // reset active filter
    filterActive = category;
  }
}
$('.f-cat').addClass('active');
$('.filtering select').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'cat-all') {
    $('.filter-cat-results .f-cat').addClass('active');
    filterActive = 'cat-all';
  } else {
    filterCategory($(this).val());
  }
});
```

```css
.filter-cat-results .f-cat {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.filter-cat-results .f-cat.active {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.65s ease forwards;
  animation: fadeIn 0.65s ease forwards;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container filtering pt-4">
  <div class="filter-cat row no-gutters mb-5">
    <h5 class="font-weight-bold">Filter by Competency</h5>
    <select class="col-sm-12 form-control">
      <option value="cat-all">Show All</option>
      <option value="xmen">X-Men</option>
      <option value="avenger">Avengers</option>
      <option value="justiceLeague" hidden>Justice League</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-3 filter-cat-results">
    <div class="col-sm-12" hidden>
      <div class="row f-cat active" data-cat="justiceLeague">
        <h3>Batman</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" hidden>
      <div class="row f-cat active" data-cat="justiceLeague">
        <h3>Flash</h3>
      </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row f-cat active" data-cat="xmen">
        <h3>Professor X</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row f-cat active" data-cat="xmen">
        <h3>Woverine</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" hidden>
      <div class="row f-cat active" data-cat="justiceLeague">
        <h3>Superman</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row f-cat active" data-cat="xmen">
        <h3>Storm</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row f-cat active" data-cat="avenger">
        <h3>Ironman</h3>
      </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row f-cat active" data-cat="avenger">
        <h3>Dr. Strange</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row f-cat active" data-cat="avenger">
        <h3>Hulk</h3>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working for me on ios 10.3.1 Safari 10. What exactly is not working in your case?

Comment: Apologies @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze, I updated the description with the problem.